# Couldn't connect JDBC to mysql?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

class JDBCTest {

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:mysql/employees";

private static final String user = "shashank";

private static final String password = "shashank14581";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Success");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please help me overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you added jdbc connector
2. make sure mysql service running
3. try to add before connection

   Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver);

Also, place exception here

David

Comment: Thanks, I added this and it works.